# CSS Grid and height 100% in safari

Tags: css, safari, height

So I have a grid made with `CSS grid` and I've got an `iframe` which is taking `100%` of the grid cell it is in, so the parent `div`, as I read on other posts safari and other browsers don't support this `height: 100%` not having a parent with a set height `value` and I'm looking for how to make it work for these browsers and how to implement it in my code.

I've quickly read about something called @support but don't really know how I could use it for this specific case; or about `flexbox` plus `webkit` to make it 100% but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Send jsfiddle url with your problem, please.

Try with:

```
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:100%
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f9f4e5xq/
So as I said I used width and height 100% to fill parent cell which is working perfectly fine exepct in safari edge, I bet you know the drill !